# iOS hiding navigation bar due to scroll amount

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've tried to implement such a table view that detects scroll amount and decides to show navigation bar or do not.

```
@interface HomeViewController () {
NSInteger scrollAmount;
bool navbarHidden = NO;
}

@implementation HomeViewController
@synthesize lastContentOffset = _lastContentOffset;
bool navbarHidden = NO;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    scrollAmount = 0;
    distance = 50;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect bounds = scrollView.bounds;
    UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
    if (offset.y > self.lastContentOffset.y)
    {
        scrollAmount++;
    }
    else
    {
        scrollAmount--;
    }
    bool awayFromTop = offset.y > distance + inset.top;
    if (awayFromTop && !navbarHidden) {
        [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        navbarHidden = YES;
    } else if (!awayFromTop || (scrollAmount < -100)) {
        [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        navbarHidden = NO;
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = offset;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    scrollAmount = 0;
}
```

Basically, `scrollViewDidScroll` counts scroll amount and if user scrolls upward, it is decrementing `scrollAmount` by minus 1.

And if `offset` is close enough to top of the screen (`!awayFromTop`) **OR** scroll amount is smaller than -100, it is expected to navigation bar is hid.

When I put a `NSLog` for `scrollAmount` program runs correct, it is hiding nav. bar when user aways from top or shows when approaches to top and `scrollAmount` is printed correctly.

But whenever `scrollAmount` reaches to -100 [`[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];` is not executed and somehow `scrollViewDidScroll` is called infinitely I mean program enters an infinite loop. `scrollAmount` is printed like -100,-101,-102...,-1005...

Then I've used below code:

```
if ([scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view].y  < heightOfScreen/-4.0f && !navbarHidden) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        navbarHidden = YES;
} else if ([scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view].y  > heightOfScreen/4.0f && navbarHidden) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        navbarHidden = NO;
}
```

Obviously [`scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:self.view].y` gives sth. similar to `scrollAmount` but it works perfect, now I wonder why my implementation has been failed. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks right but if I were you, I would use

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
```

to track the scroll view scrolling, because scrollViewDidScroll generates some weird behavior in my app too. Maybe you'd like to give a try.

Comment: Actually I have included an alternative and working solution in the question (`scrollView.panGestureRecognizer`). However I need to figure out that strange behaviour. The answer which will take the mark will be the one that gives the correct troubleshooting but thanks for your suggestion maybe some can make use of it.